# How to unpack lambda tuple parameters to run on Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, lambda, tuples

```
inflections[:, 1] = np.cumsum(inflections[:, 1])
optimalInflectionPoint = max(enumerate(inflections), key=lambda(idx, (s, v)): v)[0]
```

Above code throws an error in the following line when I try to run on Pyhton 3

```
optimalInflectionPoint = max(enumerate(inflections), key=lambda(idx, (s, v)): v)[0]
```

The description of the error, which is shown under lambda params :

*tuple parameter unpacking is not supported in Python 3*

How can I convert this tuple to run in Python 3 ? Please consider "inflections"..

Cheers,

Comment: provide reproducible example with sample data.

Comment: Why downgrade ? Only asking for how to access "tuple elements" in this context. There is already an answer for this question, so please remove downgrade in order to not to misguide people who are struggling with the same!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like `optimalInflectionPoint = max(enumerate(inflections), key=lambda v: v[1][1])[0]` would work. Just access the tuple element you want, you don't need to unpack.

Comment: Again it was showing the same error.. "tuple parameter unpacking is not supported in Python 3".. I believe because of the parentheses. (Here is the ref : https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/) . Thus, I removed the parentheses, and the error is gone. But, are you sure this is doing the same thing with my original code ? Why you ignore "s" from the list of params ? 
Btw, thank you !

Comment: Oh yes, you have a first tuple because of enumerate. So just have one parameter and unpack the tuple "manually". Updated my answer.

Comment: It all depends on what your code after is. The result is an index and the inflections, so you need to get the index.